# Why do I keep getting "Error 1: Invalid appid" for my Discord bot meant to answer queries from wolfram alpha?

Tags: python, discord, bots, wolframalpha

My appID is typed correctly, I do not know why I keep getting this response. I got this from this tutorial online: `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uqpHDvZynks`

My code relating to this command looks like this:

```
async def wolfram(ctx, *args):
  q = '+'.join(args)
  url = f"https://api.wolframalpha.com/v1/result?appid={id}&i={q}%3F"
  response = requests.get(url)
  
  if response.status_code == 501:
    await ctx.send("Cannot process")
    return
  await ctx.send(response.text)
```

Comment: Where is your `id` variable defined?

Comment: @gshpychka I did it on repl.it, and they have a secrets tab in which I can use some other variable to represent my wolframalpha bot id without actually putting it into code

Comment: They put the secrets into the environment variables, not into python variables. Did you load the value from the environment variables?